# Accessing elements in listed tuples, creating errors in my function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, syntax-error, tuples

My goal here is to get my bisect function working, as it doesn't. I want to check if item is in D, but not sure how to do that and need help..

```
def get(key, D, hasher=hash):
    try:
        item = hasher(int(key))

    except ValueError:
        item = hasher(str(key))

    for item1 in range(len(D)):
        print(D[item1])

    print()

    for value in range(len(D)):
        print(value)
        print()
        print(D[value]) 
        position = bisect.bisect_left(D[value], item)
        print(position)

D=[(0, 'richard', 69), (0, 'richard', 113), (1, 'placed', 91), (9, 'richardo', 30)]
```

I want this function to return the position (index) if the bisect function is true.

However, I wasn't sure how to check if the "item" is in my list "D". I thought I could for loop throw the range(len(D)), then use indexing to check if item is in each tuple, but it creates error.

My output:

```
[(0, 'richard', 69), (0, 'richard', 113), (1, 'placed', 91), (9, 'richardo', 30)]
(0, 'richard', 69)
(0, 'richard', 113)
(1, 'placed', 91)
(9, 'richardo', 30)

0

(0, 'richard', 69)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "binarysearch.py", line 129, in <module>
    get("richardo", D, poorhash)

  File "binarysearch.py", line 60, in get
    position = bisect.bisect_left(D[value], item)

TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Comment: its bisect.bisect_left(D[value], item) that's broken.

Comment: ok, I didn't know about bisect module, still confused what you actually called your get() with and why

Comment: ```D```needs to be sorted before using it with bisect. If you sort```D``` before searching for ```item``` you will lose the *original position information - is that ok?.  Which item/index of the tuples in ```D``` does ```item``` correspond to?

Answer (score 0):

The question of how to get the index of an element of a list when a function of the element is `True` is a basic idiom of generators or comprehensions and has the even cleaner enumerator form.

Of course they can also be written as for loops, and for loops can work from a enumerator object or rely on iteration if the argument is an iterable like a list

```
D=[(0, 'richard', 69), (0, 'richard', 113), (1, 'placed', 91), (9, 'richardo', 30)]


item = 91 # or try 'richard'

indxs = [n for n, elem in enumerate(D) if (item in elem)]
print(indxs)

for i in indxs:
    print('index:', i, '  element:', D[i])

[2]
index: 2   element: (1, 'placed', 91)
```

The Boolean comparison `(item in elem)` is "type agnostic" in the sense of not not presupposing type matching, just returns `False`, doesn't throw an error

I don't understand your intent with bisect lib function since they don't return bools, and operate only orderable objects, not mixed ints and strings

Nor do you need to play with hash functions explicitly since that's what == between tuples does internally

```
# if you want the next higher level, then compare tuples for equality

item = (9, 'richardo', 30)

indxs = [n
         for n, elem in enumerate(D)
         if (item == elem) ]

print('compare element:', indxs)

compare element: [3]
```